# Load assembly every time or only once

Tags: c#, dynamic-assemblies

I'm building an extensible service application for my work, and the way it 'extends' is by loading DLL's and executing methods within. It is designed this way so that I do not need to recompile and re-deploy every time we have a new job for it to do. Currently, the service loads a DLL using `Assembly.LoadFrom()` and then it registers the assembly with the service. In the registration, a `Func<object, bool>` is passed that dictates the entry point for the new job.

My question is would it be better if I created the instance every time I needed to run the task via something similar to this:

```
IRunable run = (IRunable)asm.CreateInstance(t.FullName, true);
run.Run();
```

or would it be better to do it the way I am currently, where I store the `Func<>` in a class that is called based of a timer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Timer!

If the performance might stuck because of it (i always had this problem in c#) u can still change it, but a timer gives you more controll over the programm itself...

But implementing a buffer should also just work fine

Comment: Would using a timer to call the creation of the instance give the best of both worlds? Or is that overkill?

Comment: a timer is always safe, just i'd had to test it myself
u have to show me more code to answer it precisly, since all in programming is situational...
i understand it is for work, but nobody can help you if you wont show anything :D